# Is it possible to connect react website with react native app?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

To be more specific, I want to make a react website that processes data then send the result to apps made by react native. Is that possible? If yes then how do I do that?

I made several google searches but no result, please help!

Comment: What you want is an API

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is called backend?

Either you make it so that it makes a post request and does long-polling on the app for the information stored "temporarily" in the database, either you use things like webhooks, signalR, MTQR, or any other communication system to have it in real time.

Feeling adventurous? You can try to make the browser communicate with the computer hardware and use the wifi/bluetooth to communicate with the external device, but I am guessing that is just not worth the trouble.